# QuartzTypeLib library and subtitles

Tags: c#, subtitle

I want to make a simple media player in C# and I used QuartzTypeLib library to read the video and this perfect. But, in the next step I want my player to support ability to add subtitle to the movie.

I googled it but i didn't find any thing that simple and useful for me.
Can any one help, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide some more details. What you have already tried? Where are you stuck? See also: [How to ask a question?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I see some solutions like VMR9 but I don't know how to use it in C# to add subtitles to video